# Find the height of frustum of a cone

Tags: geometry, volume, solid-geometry

[image: Sorry for my bad drawing]
The diagram shows a piece of wood which is obtained by cutting off the lower section of a cone.
Using PI = 3.142, calculate the value of x.

I seriously have no idea on how to find $x$.

Any helps are appreciated.

Comment: $\pi$ doesn't enter here.

Comment: Uhm actually "Calculate the value of x" is the first question, another question is find the value of the piece of wood, I'm able the solve it.

Comment: I suppose you meant volume when you said "...find the value of the piece of wood"

Comment: @Swapnil Yea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$\frac{7}{10} = \frac{10}{10+x}$

$10+x = \frac{100}{7}$

If you name the bottom apex as "O", center at radius 7 "A", Edge at radius 7 "B" and center at radius 10 "C", Edge at radius 10 "D"  Then OAB is similar to OCD by angles (AAA).

Comment: I think it would be beneficial to add that you got the relation from triangle similarity.

Comment: I refrained from it because he has not named the points.  Anyway, I will add that. No problem.

Comment: No, I was just asking you to add a line (not the whole explanation).

Comment: Why would I have to divide 7 by 10?

Comment: I don't understand >If you name the bottom apex as "O", center at radius 7 "A", Edge at radius 7 "B" and center at radius 10 "C", Edge at radius 7 "D" Then OAB is congruent to OCD by angles (AAA).

Comment: See the edit. $\angle AOB = \angle COD$ hence the result with $tan\theta$.